# Swift 3: If let statement crashes instead of executing else block

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3

I am trying to figure out how Swift 3 handles unwrapping with the `if let` syntax. My scenario is I want to make a fetch from CoreData in an `if let` statement. I want to unwrap the value there and if there is a value (not nil), then use it. If there is not a value, perform what is in the `else` block. Seems to make sense, but in my experience this is not what Swift 3 thinks.

***NOTE***: there are NO "Object" entities to be returned. I WANT it to drop down to print "No Objects".

**CODE**

```
// How I'm making the fetch from CoreData
class func getAllObjects() -> [Object]? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Object>(entityName: "Object")
    let fetched = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return fetched
}

// Unwrapping value: How I'd do it... But Xcode didn't like...
if let fetchedObjects = WorkOrder.getAllObjects() as? [Order] {
    self.objects = fetchedObjects
}
else {
    print("No Objects")
}

// Unwrapping value: How Xcode "corrected" my code and this compiles
if let fetchedObjects = WorkOrder.getAllObjects()! as [Order]? {
    self.objects = fetchedObjects
}
else {
    print("No Objects")
}
```

**WHAT HAPPENS**

The app crashes. It found nil while unwrapping an option value. I thought the `if let` was supposed to guard against my app crashing. Because if there isn't anything valid to unwrap it should execute the `else` block. Right?

**QUESTION**

Do you know of a way to have `if let` to behave in the way I suggested above? Or code that *will* behave as such?

Comment: what is the count of "fetched" just before it is returned?

Comment: There are no "Object" entities to be returned. I am trying to understand when an `if let` statement unwraps an optional that doesn't exist why does it crash instead of execute else block.

Comment: if you option click on fetchedObjects, what does it say it's type is?

Comment: `if let` unwraps optional variables.`guard` protects your code against nil values. See Paulw11's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorkOrder.getAllObjects()` will return an empty array if there are no objects, not `nil`.  And since `getAllObjects` returns an optional array of type `[Order]`, you don't need the downcast, the conditional assignment is enough.

Your code will be cleaner if you use a guard statement for the conditional assignment and the `isEmpty` test:

```
guard let fetchedObjects = WorkOrder.getAllObjects(), !fetchedObjects.isEmpty else {
    print("No Objects")
    return
}

print("There are \(fetchedObjects.count) work orders")  // Note, no need to unwrap as the guard statement has already done this
```

The way your code is written with the `try!` `getAllObjects` never return `nil`; it will either return a (possibly empty) array of `Order` or it will crash.  You should either declare `getAllObjects` as `throws` or at least return `nil` if there is a problem:

```
class func getAllObjects() -> [Object]? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Object>(entityName: "Object")
    var fetched: [Object]? = nil
    do {
        fetched = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } 
    catch() {
        print("Error fetching work orders: \(error)")
    }
    return fetched
}
```

Comment: So use `guard` always if I need to check for something that may not exist?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The guard statement helps avoid the pyramid of doom;  Note that at the end of the `guard` statement there is an `else` that fires if the guard fails.  If the guard passes then the conditionally assigned variables can be used without needing to further unwrap in the rest of the code.  If you used an `if let` then you end up with a lot of code indented inside a bunch of `if let` statements.  `guard` lets you establish values at the start of a function and then get on with things.  I edited my question to show how I don't need to unwrap `fetchedObjects` after the guard

Comment: functionally (correct me if I'm wrong, @Paulw11) guard let and if let are the same, it's more of a style thing. both unwrap your optionals, guard is more "swifty".

Comment: Both `guard` and `if let` are "Swifty" since they are part of Swift.  As I said `guard` helps avoid the pyramid of doom - http://www.thomashanning.com/the-pyramid-of-doom/

Comment: OMG. I miss Objective C.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using Objective C.  It isn't going anywhere for a long time, but to be honest I much prefer Swift to Objective C now.  It eliminates a whole class of bugs that are very easy to create with Objective C.

Comment: Sorry, it needs a change for Swift 3. I have edited now

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I will review this and get back to you.